# How to tell to gsutil file upload command that the "dst_url" is actually a file, not a directory?

Tags: gsutil

On a GCS bucket, I have uploaded from the web console a file with name `fileName`, and created a directory with the same `fileName` name. Hence, the GCS bucket contains both at its root a file with name `fileName` and a directory with the same name.

Now, when I attempt to update the `fileName` file via the `gsutil` command via

`gsutil cp localFile gs://bucketname/fileName`

where `localFile`is a file on my local machine and `gs://bucketname/fileName` is hence the `dest_url` parameter, instead of overriding the GCS `fileName` file, a new file with name `fileName` is created in the GCS directory with name `fileName`,  which yields the GCS file `gs://bucketname/fileName/fileName`.

I could not find an option in the `gsutil` command, which indicates that the provided `dest_url` should be interpreted as a file and not a directory.

Did I miss something? Any work-around, please?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to accomplish this is to use:

`gsutil rsync -d . gs://bucketname`

This command will keep the contents of filename directory but will change the contents of filename file; as a matter of fact, this command synchronizes the contents of your local path (in this case the "current" path specified by "dot": .) with the contents of your bucket, therefore, if you just change the contents of filename file in your local system, the synchronization will result in an "overwriting" of your filename file in your GCS bucket without affecting your filename directory.

Comment: This forces all the local directory files to be synchronized, @DKnight900.